# How to fix displaying animated sprites in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, android-animation, andengine, sprite-sheet

I'm new to AndEngine and programming in general. I'm using ADT.

I have refactored some code into my Resource Manager, so it will load an animated sprite for me.

The image file is in the correct asset folder, and animated fine before I moved the code into the ResourceManager.java file.

Inside my onCreateResources (in GameActivity.java), I have this:

```
  ResourceManager.getInstance().loadSpriteSheetTextures(mEngine, this);
  pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
```

In the onCreateScene method of my GameActivity.java file, I have this:

```
  animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(positionX,positionY,mTiledTextureRegion,mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
  animatedSprite.animate(25);
  mScene.attachChild(animatedSprite);
```

In my ResourceManager.java, I have this method:

```
   public synchronized void loadSpriteSheetTextures(Engine engine, Context context){
      //set our gfx asset folder
      BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
      //create a animated sprite
      BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(engine.getTextureManager(),512,512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
      mTiledTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, context, "plus.png", 6, 4);
      try{
         //
         mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource,BitmapTextureAtlas>(0,0,0));
         mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
      }catch(TextureAtlasBuilderException e){Debug.e(e);}
   }
```

I should get a spinning top, but I get the spritesheet printed to screen, with the top right borders cut off, no animation..

In LogCat, I get an error about Null pointer exception (I guess it's related).
It worked fine until I 'refactored' it into a mess ...

Please help.. What am I doing wrong?
(edited typos)

[image: the image, should be a single rotating cross]
[image: the spritesheet]
.
[image: LogCat errors]

Comment: Please post a picture if you can, and the LogCat error

Comment: hope the image helps... As i say, before refactoring, I had a single image, animating in the top left.. now i dont ..

Comment: what is line 78 in your GameActivity?

Comment: animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(positionX,positionY,mTiledTextureRegion,mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

Comment: What version of AndEngine are you using?

Comment: I'm using AndEngine 1.0